# Is the Facebook Container extension redundant with Firefox's Enhanced Tracking Protection?

Tags: firefox, privacy

Firefox now has "Enhanced Tracking Protection".  What, if any, additional privacy is provided by installing the Firefox extension "Facebook Container"?

References:

- [Today’s Firefox Blocks Third-Party Tracking Cookies and Cryptomining by Default](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2019/09/03/todays-firefox-blocks-third-party-tracking-cookies-and-cryptomining-by-default/) - The Mozilla Blog
- [Facebook Container](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/facebook-container/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox has now added *Total Cookie Protection*.  This makes the idea of a *Facebook container* much less important.  Although, it does still change some things.

When you load [a webpage with a Facebook Share or Like button](https://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/29544/the-ultimate-cheat-sheet-for-creating-social-media-buttons.aspx#facebook), *Total Cookie Protection* stops Facebook from tracking you.  Hurrah!

If you *press* the Share/Like button, deliberately or not, then Facebook will request permission to use third-party cookies.  Firefox will automatically grant this permission, because you clicked on the button.  The permission will appear inside your address bar (in the permission button, which appears to the right of the padlock icon).

That permission will be granted for *all* pages on the same website.

If you install *Facebook container*, the difference is that "embedded Facebook comments and Like buttons in tabs outside the container will not work".  In some cases the buttons may disappear, because as far as that website is concerned, you are not logged in to Facebook.

---

Regarding the original question, both Total Cookie Protection and Facebook Container are superior to the original ETP:

> Total Cookie Protection offers additional privacy protections beyond those provided by our existing anti-tracking features. Enhanced Tracking Protection (ETP), which we launched in 2018, works by blocking trackers based on a maintained list. If a party is on that list, they lose the ability to use third-party cookies. ETP was a huge privacy win for Firefox users, but we’ve known this approach has some shortcomings. If a tracker for some reason isn’t on that list, they can still track users and violate their privacy. And if an attacker wants to thwart ETP, they can set up a new tracking domain that isn’t on the list. Total Cookie Protection avoids these problems by restricting the functionality for all cookies, not just for those on a defined list.
>
> [Firefox rolls out Total Cookie Protection by default to more users worldwide](https://blog.mozilla.org/en/mozilla/firefox-rolls-out-total-cookie-protection-by-default-to-all-users-worldwide/)